# Problemas de conexão com Node e MongoDb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

Há alguns dias estou tendo um problema com um código que não estou conseguindo resolver. O que estou tentando fazer no momento é o cadastro de usuários no mongodb através do node. Estou utilizando o mecanismo de view ejs, mas até aí já verifiquei tudo e está correto, o único problema é na implementação da função que abre a conexão com o banco Mongodb. Estou utilizando o padrão MVC, segue abaixo os códigos.

Arquivo dbConnection.js que faz a conexão com o banco(até aí parece estar tudo ok):

```js
/* importar o mongodb */
var mongo = require('mongodb');

var connMongoDB = function(){
    console.log('Entrou na função de conexão');
    var db = new mongo.Db(
        'crud',
        new mongo.Server('localhost',
            27017,
            {}
        ),
        {}
    );

    return db;
};

module.exports = function(){
    return connMongoDB;
};
```

Rota cadastro.js (parece estar ok tbm):

```js
module.exports = function(application, res, res){
application.get('/cadastro', function(req, res){
    application.app.controllers.cadastro.cadastro(application, req, res);
});

application.post('/cadastrar', function(req, res){
    application.app.controllers.cadastro.cadastrar(application, req, res);
});
};
```

Controller cadastro(Até aí eu ainda fiz o teste passando um console.log da variavel dadosForm e estava retornando os dados digitados no formulário normalmente) :

```js
module.exports.cadastro = function(application, req, res){
res.render('cadastro', {validacao: {}, dadosForm: {}});
};

module.exports.cadastrar = function(application, req, res){

var dadosForm = req.body;

req.assert('nome', 'Nome não pode ser vazio').notEmpty();
req.assert('usuario', 'Usuário não pode ser vazio').notEmpty();
req.assert('senha', 'Senha não pode ser vazio').notEmpty();

var erros = req.validationErrors();

if(erros){
    res.render('cadastro', {validacao: erros, dadosForm: dadosForm});
    return;
};

var connection = application.config.dbConnection; // retorna a variável connMongoDb
var UsuariosDAO = new application.app.models.UsuariosDAO(connection); // passa a variável connMongoDb acima como parâmetro

UsuariosDAO.inserirUsuario(dadosForm);

res.send('Cadastrado com sucesso!');
};
```

Arquivo UsuariosDAO. O erro começa na linha 6 do código:

```js
function UsuariosDAO(connection){
this._connection = connection(); // recebe a variável db do arquivo dbConnection
};

UsuariosDAO.prototype.inserirUsuario = function(usuario){
this._connection.open( function(err, mongoclient){
    mongoclient.collection("users", function(err, collection){
       collection.insert(usuario);


    });
});
};

module.exports = function(){
return UsuariosDAO;
};
```

Para melhor visualização do problema, segue código de erro:

```js
TypeError: this._connection.open is not a function
at UsuariosDAO.inserirUsuario (c:\Users\micha\GitHub\Projetos-Praticos\Projeto-CRUD\app\models\UsuariosDAO.js:6:22)
at Object.module.exports.cadastrar (c:\Users\micha\GitHub\Projetos-Praticos\Projeto-CRUD\app\controllers\cadastro.js:23:17)
at c:\Users\micha\GitHub\Projetos-Praticos\Projeto-CRUD\app\routes\cadastro:7:46
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\Users\micha\GitHub\Projetos-Praticos\Projeto-CRUD\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (c:\Users\micha\GitHub\Projetos-Praticos\Projeto-CRUD\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (c:\Users\micha\GitHub\Projetos-Praticos\Projeto-CRUD\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\Users\micha\GitHub\Projetos-Praticos\Projeto-CRUD\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at c:\Users\micha\GitHub\Projetos-Praticos\Projeto-CRUD\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (c:\Users\micha\GitHub\Projetos-Praticos\Projeto-CRUD\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (c:\Users\micha\GitHub\Projetos-Praticos\Projeto-CRUD\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
```

Espero ter conseguido expor o problema corretamente. Quem puder colaborar ficarei muito grato!

Comment: Experimenta implementar usando o mongoose. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose

Comment: Vou dar uma estudada nesse módulo, já percebi que ele é o mais usado pra conexão com o banco Mongodb. De qualquer forma, se alguém souber, ainda ajudaria bastante resolver este problema com o This, acredito q seja um problema clássico ao usar o This, creio q a solução talvez esteja no uso da função bind.

Comment: Eu não analisei bem seu código porque vi que estava usando a conexão direta e eu acho complicado fazer esse gerenciamento. Mas se vc acha que o problema é o `this`. Faz assim: `var self = this`. Pronto! O seu `this` do contexto vai fixar em self.

Comment: Como seria a implementação do código q vc pensou? Tentei colocar a variável que você disse na linha 6 do código no arquivo UsuariosDAO e na linha 7 referenciei o mesmo como self._connection.open..... mas continua dando o mesmo erro, diz q o self não é uma função

Comment: vc atribuiu o valor this para self? `var self = this;`

Comment: Se eu entendi o código, vi que o problema não é no `this`, e sim no `open`. `open` não existe em `UsuariosDAO`.

To vendo que esse projeto está no github, vai ser melhor vc passar link para vermos o código completo. A comunidade poderá te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Isso! fiz exatamente dessa forma e retornou o mesmo erro. Este projeto não está no Github, o que está lá é outro semelhante. Mas eu comecei a ler sobre o mongoose e comecei a adotá-lo e têm funcionado perfeitamente. Então, não acho q seja interessante continuar nesse código se esse módulo mongodb do node não é tão utilizado e o mongoose parece bem mais completo. Agradeço imensamente a disponibilidade em ajudar e a recomendação do mongoose q foi muito útil.